# error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Tcl'

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, cx-freeze

I made a tkinter app on my mac which runs well, when I run it from the terminal. Now, I want to make an executable version of it, but I get this error message after python setup.py build:

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Tcl'
```

setup.py:

```
import cx_Freeze, sys
import os
import os
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "/System/Library/tcl/8.4"
base = None

if sys.platform == 'Win32':
base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("multiframe.py", base=base)]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name="cu",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"]}},
    version= "0.01",
    description = "dasdasd",
    executables = executables
    )
```

I know that something is wrong with the tcl import but I have tcl in Python3.6 folder on windows but I don't in mac

Comment: So you're running Py3 on Windows but Py2 on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

In your *options* statement, you tell the system to import the "tkinter" package.  "tkinter" is Python 3. "Tkinter" is for Python 2. If you are running Python 2 on your Mac, you need to use "Tkinter" instead of "tkinter" for a package. And, of course, you'll need to make sure your "cu" app runs on Python 2.

Also, the line

```
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "/System/Library/tcl/8.4"
```

points to an old version of Tcl.  Probably doesn't matter. But the later Python 2.7 and Python 3 both come with 8.5.  You should probably upgrade your Mac to Python 3 to be the same as your Windows machine, so that your code will run in both places. Otherwise you may need little tweaks in your code to get the same code to run on both.